# PHP - how to catch response from oracle procedure?

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures

all. I have a question about catching a response from oracle procedure..
That is my procedure :

```
PROCEDURE generate_receipt_simop(in_receipt_number IN VARCHAR2, in_inv_status IN VARCHAR2, in_kode_cabang IN VARCHAR2, out_status OUT VARCHAR2, out_message OUT VARCHAR2)is
v_result_simop              NUMBER  DEFAULT 0;
out_status_simop            VARCHAR2(100)   DEFAULT NULL;
out_errormessage_simop      VARCHAR2(100)   DEFAULT NULL;
v_org_id                    NUMBER  DEFAULT 0;

BEGIN    
************
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        logf('ROLLBACK (RECEIPT)');
        ROLLBACK;
        out_status     := 'F';
        out_message    := 'GENERATE FAILED (RECEIPT) '|| in_receipt_number ||SQLERRM;          
    END;
```

I try to call and read a response using php, like this :

```
$param_xpi= array(
                        "in_receipt_number"=>"$x",
                        "in_receipt_status"=>"Y",
                        "in_kode_cabang"=>"PTK",
                        "out_status"=>"",
                        "out_message"=>""
                        );

            $sql_xpi = "DECLARE
            in_receipt_number VARCHAR2(50) DEFAULT '$x';
            in_kode_cabang VARCHAR2(3) DEFAULT 'PTK';
            out_status VARCHAR2(1) DEFAULT '';
            out_message VARCHAR2(240) DEFAULT '';
            in_inv_status VARCHAR2(1) DEFAULT 'Y';
            BEGIN
            XPI2.XPI2_AR_API_RECEIPT_PKG.generate_receipt_simop(in_receipt_number, in_inv_status, in_kode_cabang, out_status, out_message);
            dbms_output.put_line('Generate Status : ' || out_status);
            dbms_output.put_line('Message Status : ' || out_message);
            END;";

            $result = $db_simkeu->query($sql_xpi, $param_xpi);

            print_r($result);

            $out_status1 = $param_xpi['out_status'];
            $out_message = $param_xpi['out_message'];
```

But, variable $out_status1 and $out_message is always null. I think something wrong with my method to listen a response at this php code.
Please, help

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your code throws any exception? Exception handler `WHEN OTHERS` works only if (any) exception occurs. So if your code does not throw an exception then your values remains null.

Comment: Actually, I have intention to ask about 
$result = $db_simkeu->query($sql_xpi, $param_xpi);
is it true syntax to execute and get response from procedure? 
I just get an example like that but it seems $param_xpi just shows the default value. $param_xpi doesn't get any other value from that execution

Comment: I don't know PHP, unfortunately. Try your code in SQL*Plus first to examine its result. If it returns other values other than default, then the problem is in PHP call.

Comment: Yes, it's successfully running at TOAD for Oracle. the variable shows it's result. I'm pretty sure something wrong in my php code. But, I'm still fixing it now, I still can't figure out about the problem... Oh.. Please somebody help, I also try `oci_bind_by_name` but still not running

Comment: Look at this: [http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2009/07/03/php-out-mode-parameter/](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2009/07/03/php-out-mode-parameter/). I hope it helps.